# How to use a Vue instance as data

Tags: vue.js

I want to put in the DOM an array of *Vue* instances.

```
Tree = Vue.extend

    props: ["foo"]

    template: "(Tree : {{foo}})"


Forest = Vue.extend

    components:
        tree: Tree

    data: ->
        forest: []

    template: "<tree v-for=\"tree in forest\">"

    created: ->
        for i in [0...10]
            @forest.$set i, new Tree foo: i


new Forest
    el: "body"
    replace: false
```

Obviously, in my real code, the `forest` array changes during the lifecycle of the application.

This code creates 20 trees, 10 in the DOM and 10 in the `forest` array. What I want is to pass the 10 trees from the array to the DOM. I suppose I need to change the template `"<tree v-for=\"tree in forest\">"` but I have no idea how.

Answer (score 0):

One way to iterate the trees in an example forest template:

```
    template: "#forest-template",
    compiled: function(){
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            this.forest.push({foo:i})
        }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="forest-template">
    <template v-for="tree in forest">
        <tree v-bind:foo="tree.foo"></tree>
    </template>
</div>
```